# Objective-C - NSData to integer does not work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata

I'm trying to convert 2 bytes in a NSData to an int.
Using the code

```
int value = *(int*)[d1 bytes];
NSLog(@"NSData: %@ -> int: %d",d1, value);
```

i'll get

> NSData: <01ac> -> int: 44033

which is int for ac01 not 01ac.
What would be the way to convert it in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the byte order is switched (i.e. big endian vs. little endian).

To fix this, try:

```
int value = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(*(int*)[d1 bytes]);
```